Why are the syslog severity level keywords error and warn (and panic) deprecated?
According to the Wikipedia Syslog page with reference to the syslog.conf manpage, the severity level keywords panic, error and warn are deprecated, replaced by emerg, err and warning respectively.
I can understand an obvious rationale for deprecating panic, the implications of the word aren't necessarily helpful or appropriate and emergency is a reasonable alternative.
However, replacing error with the abbreviated err but replacing warn with the extended warning seem inconsistent. The resulting keywords are an unusual mix of full and abbreviated words with no obvious pattern.
RFC5424 defines syslog but does not mention keywords (only numeric and full text descriptions of the levels), so it's not obvious where these are formally defined and who has deprecated them.
So I am curious:

Why was a change needed to the error and warning severities, and
Why was the whole set not made more consistent (for example either abbreviations emerg, alert, crit, err, warn, note, info, debug or alternatively full words  emergency, alert, critical, error, warning, notice, informational, debug)


"Why" is outside our scope: Stack Overflow is only focused on practical questions -- those whose answers are expected to change how you go about the practice of writing code.

(That said, https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/basedefs/syslog.h.html is a reference source you're missing -- present in issue 8 published as of 2024, and naming the levels at hand)
